# How to accept either of two types

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to deal with cases for type.

I have callback function property which its argument has two types string or number in the React Functional Component

```
interface InputProps {
  getValue?: (value: string | number) => void;
}

const Input: React.FC<InputProps> = (props) => { ... }
```

And I want to pass getRegistraionId function which has string argument into `Input` that is Functional Component.

```
 const getRegistrationId = (registrationId: string) => {
    setRegistrationId(registrationId);
  };
```

I expected it will be accepted because getValue has argument which has two types string or number, but

```
Type '(registrationId: string) => void' is not assignable to type '(value: string | number) => void'.
```

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `registrationId` type only accepts a `string` but `getValue` can accept a `string` or `number`. If you want `getValue` to accept a function that takes either or then you want `getValue` to take 2 versions of a function.

Example:

```
type FunctionType = ((value: string) => void) | ((value: number) => void);

const doSomethingWithString: FunctionType = (value: string) => {
  console.log(value);
};
const doSomethingWithNumber: FunctionType = (value: number) => {
  console.log(value);
};
```